# AutoMapper tries to map DbModel to dateTime

Tags: automapper-4

so here is mapping definition:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<EditMovieModel, Video>()
            .ForAllMembers(options => options.ResolveUsing<CustomMovieMapper>());
```

I have defined my custom resolver:

```
public class CustomMovieMapper : ValueResolver<EditMovieModel, Video>
{

    protected override Video ResolveCore(EditMovieModel source)
    {
        Video video = new Video();
        video.ID = source.ID;
        video.Name = source.Name;
        video.Description = source.Description;
        video.Thumbnail = source.Thumbnail;
        video.FileURL = source.FileURL;
        video.InsertionDate = video.InsertionDate!= null ? video.InsertionDate : DateTime.Now;
        video.Director = source.Director;
        video.Actors = source.Actors;
        video.ProductionDate = DateTime.Now;
        switch (source.MovieType)
        {
            case UIMovieType.Irainian:
                {
                    video.Language = Language.Irainian;
                    video.VideoType = VideoType.Movie;
                    video.Character = Character.Real;
                }
                break;
            case UIMovieType.Foriegn:
                {
                    video.Language = Language.Foriegn;
                    video.VideoType = VideoType.Movie;
                    video.Character = Character.Real;
                }
                break;
            case UIMovieType.Cartoon:
                {
                    video.VideoType = VideoType.Movie;
                    video.Character = Character.Cartoon;
                }
                break;
            case UIMovieType.Documentary:
                {
                    video.VideoType = VideoType.Documentary;
                }
                break;
            case UIMovieType.Theater:
                {
                    video.VideoType = VideoType.Theater;
                }
                break;
        }

        return video;
    }
}
```

and in my controller Action method:

```
Video movie = _videoRepository.Get(m => m.ID == movieViewModel.ID).SingleOrDefault();
            if(movie == null)
            {
                movie = new Video();
            }
movie = Mapper.Map(movieViewModel, movie);
```

when mappeing occurs, I get this exception:

```
 Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
    Mapping types:
Video -> Nullable`1
NTV.Data.Model.Video -> System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

Destination path:
Video.ProductionDate.ProductionDate

Source value:
NTV.Data.Model.Video
```

but I'm not mapping Video to ProductionDate explicity. whats wrong? what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I was wrong here is that I was using `CustomReslover` instead of using `ITypeConverter` interface. CustomResolver is used for chnage the behavior of mapping for properties not the entire object, hence this is the reason is saw that error. 
here I wanted to customize the entire behavior of mapping so this is the way:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EditMovieModel, Video>()
            .ConvertUsing(new CustomMovieMapper());

public class CustomMovieMapper : ITypeConverter<EditMovieModel, Video>
{
    public Video Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        EditMovieModel source = (EditMovieModel)context.SourceValue;
        Video video = (Video)context.DestinationValue;

        video = video ?? new Video();
        video.ID = source.ID;
        video.Name = source.Name;
        ........
        return video;
    }
}
```